# Why do some UI elements in Unity have an anchor point feature and others don't?

Tags: unity-game-engine, layout, anchorpoint

I am currently working on a smartphone app in Unity and have developed a prefab as the basis for each app-page. Now I want to set the anchor points of the various UI elements in this prefab, so that the back button, for example, always stays at the top left.

The button in the inspector, which is needed to set the anchor point is not visible for some reason. It looks like a small square, see in the picutres. Why do some UI Elements have this and others do not?

[image: Inspector without anchor point function]

[image: Inspector with anchor point function]

Comment: looks like all mine do......

Comment: seems because your upper one is not nested below a `RectTransform`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out! If the UI Element is a child of an object that does not have a Rect Transform component, then the UI Element itself loses its pivot point as well.